# Coords on Page Load Server Side

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, navigator, coords

So I am trying to record location coordinates on page load of asp.net page. The problem is the values of my hidden fields do not exists until the page is fully loaded. I have tried to capture on unload event hoping it was further after the rendering etc. to no avail as the server is still serving. I simply want to write my data to my db on page load event. I do not want the user to have to click a button to record the data as I am able to do that but do not want the extra input from user required.

Get Coords Code JS:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    function showPosition(position) {
    $("[id*=hdnLatitude]").val(position.coords.latitude);
    $("[id*=hdnLongitude]").val(position.coords.longitude);
                    },
function (error) {
        }, {
        enableHighAccuracy: true
        , timeout: 5000
       }
    );
```

On Page Load Event ASP.Net:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
   'write to my db
End Sub
```

So I know how to write to the database on page load but as I said above, the hidden fields do not have any data in them yet. My question is how I get the data in them either before page load. This does not seem possible as it has not served the client yet but can I force a postback or something on page load to get these values as they will have loaded by then? I really do not want to have the page flash on the user either i.e. load twice. Hope this makes sense. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So I decided to use an Ajax Timer. I set it to 6000 and it fires on server side and does what I need. I put it inside an update panel and it fires without reloading the whole page. Maybe not the best solution but does the job.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Timer ID="tmrRecord" runat="server" Interval="6000">
</asp:Timer>
<asp:Label ID="lblLocation" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>



Protected Sub tmrRecord_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrRecord.Tick
    'record coords to database
    tmrRecord.Enabled = False
End Sub
```